# Exact sequence out of commutative exact diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, exact-sequence

I'm trying to get grip on the following commutative exact diagram:

[image: Commutative exact diagram]

I know where the maps come from and could verify the exactness and the other maps. (It is induced by the long exact sequence of Poitou-Tate, a local duality theorem and the definitions of the groups).

But now there is a lemma implying that we have an exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow Ш^1(k_S,A') \rightarrow Ш^1(k_S,S \setminus T, A') \rightarrow coker^1(k_S,T,A)^\vee \rightarrow 0$$

I cannot see where the surjective map in this exact sequence comes from. I see, that for $s \in Ш^1(k_S,S \setminus T,A')$ we can map it to an element in the restricted product $\prod_S H^1(k_\mathfrak{p},A')$ by choice of an preimage. But from there I do not see any connection.

Does somebody has a hint how to proceed?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to explain a diagram chase in writing, but I'll try:

Let $x \in Ш^1(k_S, S \setminus T, A')$, map it to $y \in H^1(k_S | k, A')$ then to $z \in \prod_S H^1(k_\mathfrak{p}, A')$. The image of $z$ in $\prod_{S \setminus T} H^1(k_\mathfrak{p}, A')$ is zero by exactness of the first row, so actually $z \in \prod_T H^1(k_\mathfrak{p}, A')$. $z$ is mapped to $u$ in $\prod_T H^1(k_\mathfrak{p}, A')^\vee$. This $u$ is mapped to zero in $H^1(k_S|k, A)^\vee$, because of the exactness of the first row: $z$ came from $y \in H^1(k_S | k, A')$. Therefore $u \in \mathrm{coker}^1(k_S, T, A)^\vee$.

I'll leave you to check that this map is well-defined. It's surjective, because if $u$ is in the cokernel, you can map it to the "restricted product$^\vee$" and then to the "restricted product" (because of the iso), then it's easy enough to show that everything comes from an $x \in Ш^1(k_S, S \setminus T, A')$. Then the kernel is computed easily enough (it's very mechanical).

Hopefully this helps:

[image: comm diag]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was even more than I expected and helped me a lot. Do you know about general rules how commutative diagrams and exact sequences "work" together except for the snake lemma or the Five lemma? Thanks again!

Comment: There's no real general rule, it's a lot of "hand crafting". The general method is known as diagram chasing, you need to practice to get good at it.

Comment: Yeah, I know this but it is always a mess, and sometimes - as seen in this post - I don't know about the right next step yet. So that's why I'm asking about general rules of "degenerating commutative diagrams" in order to simplify such monsters as above :-)

Comment: Well more than often you can reduce everything to a contrived application of the snake lemma (in this example as well, I think), but it's in my opinion easier to work everything out by hand.